# Cancelling a setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an alert popup which appears when a certain action takes place. After 5 seconds the alert popup is hidden, using `setTimeout()`.

The problem I am having is, if I trigger the popup multiple times, sometimes the subsequent popups appear but disappear straight away. This, I believe is because the previous timeout is still in progress.

I have tried to cancel the timeout using `clearTimeout()` but this doesn't make any difference. See code below:

```
function showAlert() {
    var elem = $('#alert');
    var alertTimeout;

    elem.addClass('active');

    if (alertTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(alertTimeout);
    }

    alertTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.removeClass('active');
    }, 5000);
}
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Declare `alertTimeout` outside the function, else it'll just get GC'd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `alertTimeout` variable goes away when the function returns. You need to move it outside the function:

```
var alertTimeout; // <==========================
function showAlert() {
    var elem = $('#alert');

    elem.addClass('active');

    if (alertTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(alertTimeout);
    }

    alertTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.removeClass('active');
    }, 5000);
}
```

---

Side note: Ideally, this code is in a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or a scoping block where you use `let` instead of `var` (ES2015+) or a scoping function (ES5 and earlier) so that `alertTimeout` and `showAlert` aren't global.

If for some legacy support reason `showAlert` *has* to be global, you can still keep `alertTimeout` from being global like this:

```
var showAlert = (function() {
    var alertTimeout;
    return function showAlert() {
        var elem = $('#alert');

        elem.addClass('active');

        if (alertTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(alertTimeout);
        }

        alertTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            elem.removeClass('active');
        }, 5000);
    };
})();
```

(Note that that means `showAlert` is no longer hoisted.)